# How to make API HTML report with the help of command prompt other then newman?

Tags: web-api-testing

How to make API HTML report with the help of command prompt other then newman ?

Hi,

I have already try to make API HTML report with the help of newman but In that I won't be able to get Falied call report properly.

So,Can any one help me how i can get my failed API count as well ?

Following command I have used in command prompt:

-newman -c exportedfile.json -H Report.html

Answer (score 2):

please check newman version if its 3.2.0 then refer https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman   for updated options some of them have been deprecated and are scheduled to be discontinued soon.
Following command may work

```
newman run exportedfile.json --reporters html
```

Comment: Hi Pratik,

Thanks! for you reply but I want to know the results regarding failed called which I won't be able to get.

which you have given is doing same as command I have mentioned.

can you please provide me proper solution ?

Comment: so does this make files? where? I get nothing?

Comment: There should be a directory with name newman which holds all those result files.